# AFNetworking POST Request failed Code=-1011 (400)

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, http-status-code-400

Для проверки POST запросов я использую небольшую утилиту POSTMAN.
Мои настройки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для отправки POST запроса я использую AFNetworking. Вот мой код:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"offset": @"1", @"csrf-token": @"63b164ea557b4aba694f81520c71972fa43a9772"};
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:@"http://simple.com/" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Но я получаю такую ошибку:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x7a6c5240 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7a6b5360> { URL: http://simple.com/ } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, private, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sun, 31 May 2015 15:40:26 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
    "Set-Cookie" = "csrf-token=5589461e87b28a538953ccac4168bf1f98b20b1ds%3A40%3A%22f52bda5262260a3ee0a10efcf48a6a49c11e4103%22%3B; path=/, PHPSESSID=803db60816b9f8203fb8feca01c130b6; path=/";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.17";
```

Так же я пробовал использовать NSURLConection. Код:

```
NSString *post = @"offset=1&csrf-token=63b164ea557b4aba694f81520c71972fa43a9772";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://simple.com/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"~~~~~ Status code: %d", [response statusCode]);
```

Но я снова получаю ошибку 400

Кто может помочь решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил свою проблему.

Дело в том, что сервер хранит сессию с определенным **CSRF token**. Моя ошибка была в том, что я использовал один и тот же токен, как в браузере, так и в мобильном устройстве. Поэтому сервер и не отдавал данные, так как получал неверный POST запрос.

**Мое решение:** я сначала получаю с сервера **CSRF token**, а потом для дальнейших `POST` запросов я использую полученный токен. В ответ на POST запрос я получаю статус 200 и нужные мне данные.

Правда `AFNetworking` мне не совсем помог в этой проблеме, поэтому пришлось использовать стандартный `NSURLConnection` (код я прикладывал в вопросе). Может на будущее кому-то это пригодиться!

Всем спасибо! Всем удачи!

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking скорее всего выдает ошибку изза ответа сервера, который приходит в виде text/html:

```
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

По идеи Content-Type должен быть application/json.

Или поменяй requestSerializer.

Comment: На сервер идет Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8. От сервера Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

У вас реквест в AFNetworking сериализуется как JSON, а в Postman - как form-data. Поэтому не работает AFNetworking.